# Converting [[UIColor]] double Array to UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, uicolor

I am working on a filter app which required breaking down a `UIImage` into a matrix of pixels, `[[UIColor]]` essentially.

After I do my operations, I need to convert my `[[UIColor]]` back to a `UIImage`, but I cannot find a method to do so.

The only thing I find is a `.setFill(color)` which is setting the whole image to have a single color.

Is there anything like `.setData(color:[[UIColor]])`? This is what I used to go from `UIImage` -> to a color matrix (found this here in Stack Overflow...)

```
extension UIImage {
    func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

        var pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.CGImage))
        var data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        var pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

        var r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        var g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        var b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        var a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to convert it back?

Answer (score -1):

#### Sort of...

First, you should be aware that a `UIImage` is just a wrapper for something else, most likely a `CGImage`. `UIColor` is mostly meant for use when using drawing commands so you could create a [CGContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html) and draw a series of 1x1px rects. This isn't really what you want.

#### Create a struct

You want to create a struct to hold your color values.

```
struct PixelData 
{
    var red: UInt8
    var green: UInt8
    var blue: UInt8
    var alpha: UInt8
}
```

So by having this struct you have an intermediate form that is pretty simple and can then be written out to a CGImage very easily once you stuff this data into [PixelData]. Note: that this is 1-D array with width times height PixelsData structs, with one row of data followed by another.